# iOS Parse Query - Percentage Logging Different Numbers

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I'm returning 2 different queries from Parse...1 for a likeCount and 1 for a dislikeCount.
When I query for each and set them equal to their respective labels they come out correct.  I am now trying to get a percentage of likes by dividing the likeCount by the likeCount+dislikeCount.

The query is run when a button is pressed and a push segue is initialized.  Sometimes this logs the correct numbers (usually the first time).  However, usually after the first time the query is run and one or maybe both of the numbers values don't update and it outputs the labels initial text.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) float likeCount;
@property (nonatomic, assign) float dislikeCount;


- (void)queryForUserActivity
{
    //Create an Array to check either user photo
    NSArray *userPhotos = @[self.firstUserPhoto, self.secondUserPhoto];

    PFQuery *queryForLikes = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kDDActivityClassKey];
    [queryForLikes whereKey:kDDActivityTypeKey equalTo:kDDActivityTypeLikeKey];
    [queryForLikes whereKey:kDDActivityFirstUserPhotoKey containedIn:userPhotos];
    [queryForLikes whereKey:kDDActivitySecondUserPhotoKey containedIn:userPhotos];
    [queryForLikes countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError *error) {
        self.totalLikesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", number];
    }];

    PFQuery *queryForDislikes = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kDDActivityClassKey];
    [queryForDislikes whereKey:kDDActivityTypeKey equalTo:kDDActivityTypeDislikeKey];
    [queryForDislikes whereKey:kDDActivityFirstUserPhotoKey containedIn:userPhotos];
    [queryForDislikes whereKey:kDDActivitySecondUserPhotoKey containedIn:userPhotos];
    [queryForDislikes countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError *error) {
        self.totalDislikesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", number];
    }];

    PFQuery *queryForApprovalPercent = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[queryForLikes, queryForDislikes]];
    [queryForApprovalPercent countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            self.likeCount = [self.totalLikesLabel.text floatValue];
            self.dislikeCount = [self.totalDislikesLabel.text floatValue];
            NSLog(@"%f", self.likeCount);
            NSLog(@"%f", self.dislikeCount);
            float approvalPercentage = (self.likeCount / (self.likeCount + self.dislikeCount)) * 100.0;
            self.approvalPercentageLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.0f%%", approvalPercentage];
            if (approvalPercentage < 5) self.approvalPercentageLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: You are using instance variables inside a block- are you sure they're not being mutated during execution? Also, you're updating your UI from a background thread (label text color, label text). That's a big no-no.

Comment: Thanks @Stonz2.  As far as the UI edits, i tried setting the number to the likeCount/dislikeCount (self.likeCount = number; , self.dislikeCount = number;) but then I can't call them outside the background thread.  Do you know how else you could access these variables from outside the background thread?

Comment: You can keep your code almost the same as it is, just dispatch your operations to the main queue inside your block to ensure that they are executed synchronously and that UI operations are main-threaded (personally I prefer `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{//do stuff on main thread here});`)